# power bi show confirmation popup on redirecting to external website

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

Can we show a pop while redirecting to external websites on click of the link
[confirmation pop up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7J8D.png)

Comment: No, it is not supported.

Comment: @AndreyNikolov, thanks for the response, 
apart for Data visualization is there any feature where we can make api call on button click to post data for example, update the data verse data using post api call

Comment: You can use Power Apps and Power Apps visual.